# How do I get the platform from OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt

I want to do an upgrade to an OpenWRT router. I know how to run `sysupgrade` on it to upgrade it, but how do I find the platform I'm running to download a newer version from,

```
http://downloads.openwrt.org/
```

In Debian, you can find it out with `uname` but OpenWRT doesn't show it,

```
# OpenWRT
root@OpenWrt:/mnt# uname -p
unknown

# Debian
$ uname -p
x86_64
```

Even better would be a tool that would give me the full sysupgrade url, something like this

```
http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/<platform>/generic/openwrt-<platform>-generic-<hardware>-jffs2-sysupgrade.bin
```

One of the answers didn't know what the *platform* was in reference too, [here is the list](http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/):

```
adm5120 adm8668 ar7 ar71xx at91
atheros au1000 brcm2708 brcm47xx brcm63xx
cns3xxx cobalt ep93xx ixp4xx kirkwood
lantiq malta mcs814x mpc52xx mpc83xx
omap4 orion ppc40x ramips x86
xburst
```

Comment: "cat /etc/banner" doesn't show?

Comment: @DanilaLadner nope, just shows http://pastebin.com/wLztKcEY

Comment: Right this is your svn version r39263 from that trunk.

Answer (score 6):

Source `/etc/openwrt_release` and use the variables that sets for you.

Comment: Is there a script that will automatically use these to download a newer version? Like a dist-upgrade on debian?

Comment: pass, not an OpenWRT expert, sorry.  I tend to treat upgrades like that rather seriously on OpenWRT boxes, and have prepped for recovery in case the upgrade goes wrong, since such upgrades risk taking out my wife's Internet. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Gives a lot of useful information, including the Router Model Number (but not, in my case, version number).

Answer (score 0):

One way, though I'm not sure it's the *most* right way is to read `opkg.conf`,

```
root@OpenWrt:/# cat /etc/opkg.conf 
src/gz barrier_breaker http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages
dest root /
dest ram /tmp
lists_dir ext /var/opkg-lists
option overlay_root /overlay
```

The line that says,

```
src/gz barrier_breaker http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages
```

Gives it away in the URL **`ar71xx`**.